# Grunt copy / ant pattern / omit variable directory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I need copy files from folder src/plugin@x.x.x to dist/plugin.

Version can be changed so I want to omit version number everywhere.
I do:

```
files[{
    cwd: 'src'
    src: 'plugin@*/**/*'
    dest: 'dist/plugin'
}];
```

But it copy my files to dist/plugin/plugin@x.x.x directory.

I want my files in dist/plugin directory (without specify x.x.x in grunt task).

Answer (score 0):

You want the `flatten` option. I think you also need `expand` for `flatten` to work:

```
files: [ {
    cwd: 'src'
    src: 'plugin@*/**/*'
    dest: 'dist/plugin',
    expand: true,
    flatten: true
} ],
```

Comment: Flatten option will destroy structure of plugin making it flat. I need to keep structure below plugin folder unchanged.

Comment: Does `src: 'plugin@*'` do what you want?

Comment: No. I think only any function can handle my problem but I prefer gulp over grunt and I really don't know how can I process that.
options.process function doen't seem to work.